# Comparing two columns of different groups having 4 columns in each group, and inserting empty row wheren the column do not match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2013

Comparing 2 columns from 2 different groups having a empty column between the groups , each group containing 4 columns, inserting the cell in every column of a group 1 if column D of group 1, do not match with column I of group 2 or inserting the cell in every column of group 2 if column I of group 2, do not match with column D of group 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to compare two Columns.

First Column D with Column L and second is Column L with D.

Anywhere in blank cell write this Formula will compare Column D with L.

=IF((ISERROR(MATCH(D2,$L$2:$L$20,0))),D2,"")

Drag down the Formula till its required.

Now, this one will compare Column L with D.

=IF((ISERROR(MATCH(L2,$D$2:$D$20,0))),L2,"")

Drag it down also.

**NB:** *First Formula will find out Value which are in Column D but not in Column L and second will do the reverse of it. Since you have not specified what for you are comparing so that I've created this example will help you further.*

Comment: @pnuts,, I've include the ISERROR for the blanks and this is a tested solution, will work,, if receiving error ,, just write the Error message.